# Read java.io.File from mysql blob

Tags: java, mysql, blob

I have the below code which stores a List to File and then to a mysql blob column. Is it possible to recover that List from the database?

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

File tempFile = File.createTempFile("myFile.temp");

tempFile.deleteOnExit();

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeUnshared(myList);
objectOutputStream.close();

String trailQuery = "INSERT INTO table (tempFile) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(trailQuery);
preparedStatement.setObject(1, tempFile);
```

I tried to read that but I get a FileNotFoundException

```
if (resultSet.next()) {

    InputStream fileInputStream = resultSet.getBinaryStream("tempFile");
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    File inner = (File) objectInputStream.readObject();
    FileInputStream fileInputStreamInner = new FileInputStream(inner);
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStreamInner = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStreamInner);

    ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) objectInputStreamInner.readObject();
    System.out.println(myList.size());
}
```

Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \tmp\myFile.1708309680603860570.temp (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: Check what exactly gets stored in the database on insert. I'm not a [tag:mysql] expert but it might be not what you expect.

Comment: Also post the full exception stack trace and point to the line of code where it happens.

Comment: A `java.io.File` is nothing more than a holder for a filename. Saving a filename into a database doesn't save its content. Rethink.

Comment: Do not save the file to the blob. Save the List to the blob.

Answer (score 0):

As @EJP mentioned a java.io.File is nothing more than a holder for a filename... had wrong understanding - so none of the contents of the files are there....